# How can i optimize an oracle procedure used to copy data from tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, cursor, procedure

I have two different tables in my `oracle` database. I would copy only part of data of my first table (`ANOTHER_TABLE`), selecting only some column and filtering the rows, into a new one (`NEW_TABLE`).

I tried with the following procedure, using cursor, but i registers long execution time.
How can i optimize this `oracle sql` procedure? It is possible?

For information, the `ANOTHER_TABLE` contains about 500k records.

```
PROCEDURE IMPORT_DATA
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE
      c_FIELD1 ANOTHER_TABLE.FIELD1%type;
      c_FIELD2 ANOTHER_TABLE.FIELD2%type;
      row_found NUMBER;
      CURSOR c
      IS
        (
        -- choose only valid data
        SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2
        FROM ANOTHER_TABLE
        WHERE FIELD2 = '1'
        ) ;
    BEGIN
      OPEN c;
      LOOP
        FETCH c INTO c_FIELD1, c_FIELD2;
        EXIT
      WHEN c%notfound;
        BEGIN
          -- verify the record existance to decide if it is 
          -- necessary an update or an insert operation
          SELECT 1
          INTO row_found
          FROM NEW_TABLE
          WHERE FIELD1 = c_FIELD1;
          -- update record
          UPDATE NEW_TABLE
          SET FIELD2 = c_FIELD2
          WHERE FIELD1 = c_FIELD1;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          -- insert record
          INSERT
          INTO NEW_TABLE
            (
              FIELD1,
              FIELD2
            )
            VALUES
            (
              c_FIELD1,
              c_FIELD2
            );
        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
          -- duplicated record
          -- show error!
        END;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c;
      COMMIT;
    END;
```

I would copy only same data of one table into another one in the fastest way. How can i optimize it?

Thank you

Comment: Anything done row-by-row is likely to be slow. Have you considered a `merge`, which could be used in a procedure but doesn't need to be? Do you actually have duplicates in the new table, and if so shouldn't they be sanitized before you start? If you have to stick with this patten then using collections and bulk operations would improve things, but still wouldn't be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the fastest way to do things is with a single query, not with cursors.  If you want to insert new, distinct values into `NEW_TABLE` (as the title suggests), then you can do this with a single `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE(FIELD1, FIELD2)
    SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1, FIELD2
    FROM ANOTHER_TABLE A
    WHERE FIELD2 = '1' AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM NEW_TABLE N
                      WHERE A.FIELD1 = N.FIELD1
                     );
```

Your code is updating data as well.  For this, you can use `MERGE` or just delete the duplicate rows first:

```
DELETE FROM NEW_TABLE
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ANOTHER_TABLE A
                  WHERE A.FIELD1 = N.FIELD1
                 );
```

And then run the above query.